# How to output abbreviated currency symbol instead of currency name when using money_format()?

Tags: php, money-format

Is there a flag in the money_format function that lets you replace the long currency (e.g. USD, EUR) with the abbreviated version ($, €)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: the documentation specifies the "n" flag for the current locale's national currency format:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
echo money_format('%n', 7.99); // £7.99

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');
echo money_format('%n', 7.99); // $7.99
```

Make sure you set a locale for LC_MONETARY (or LC_ALL, of course).

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. You should mention that the locale depends on the platform and different platforms have different naming mechanisms as seen here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: @0A0D true, I should have mentioned that. I apologise for not giving adequate warning :-)

Comment: this seems to print Eu 100,00 for "nl_NL" instead of "€ 100,00"

Comment: The important thing here is the ".UTF-8", not the "n" flag!!